# 100% usage cpu in App Engine managed VM

Tags: google-app-engine

I've deployed https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere as an app engine managed vm.

Every 3 days, without the having any usage, the cpu of the managed vm goes to 100%, the cors-anywhere keeps on working, although slower. Forcing a reboot on the managed vm, fixes the problem for 3 days.

What might be the cause of the cpu going to 100%?

Comment: Do you have any logs? Any scheduled jobs? Any... thing that you do in every 3 days?

Comment: The logs are all normal. There are no scheduled jobs. Also have this problem in another managed vms. It seems that there is some software component that google installs in their managed vm's that has some bug, maybe cadvisor.

Comment: Well, since the Managed VMs are currently in beta, I suggest you to fill up a bug report describing your problem.

Comment: We are experiencing the exact same problem on 4 different modules. (We are using Dart)

Comment: As is, this question is far too broad to really have a specific, technical answer.  I would strongly advise filing a [defect report](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry) on the related issue tracker and provide as much detail as possible on the observed behavior if this is still an issue for you.